# Is it bad to only allow users to sign in using Google?

Tags: web, google-signin, account

Is it necessarily a bad thing if the users of my app can only sign in using Google? I don't particularly want to create my own login system; I don't trust myself to handle keys, salts, hashes, and databases without messing something up. I know that not all users have Google accounts, but is it 'good enough'? Sorry if this is a more general discussion/opinion question. I understand if it gets removed.

Comment: Personally I think it's great. Having to create a separate log in for each site or app is a mess, this kind of centralization is exactly what the Internet needs.

Comment: Check out something like Firebase Auth or Auth0 for hosted login systems complete with UI and supporting Google, Facebook, username/password, etc. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's alright. Most people do have a Google account these days. But I think some might not be happy about having to give permissions and data to your app. As in a new sign up is a fresh start. But linking to Google might make them feel less secure because their old account is now linked to something they are not sure whether to trust or not.